# When is a good time to implement/call startActivityForResult() and then onActivityResult() on Fragment or on Activity?

Tags: android

I am currently stuck to a problem since I notice my application not updating the list adapter I created. I called MyFragment.onNoteListUpdated() (A function which notifies the list of the changes) was not being properly called on Activity.onActivityResult(). I called startActivityForResult() on Activity and receive the result from the same Activity as well. I read SO about this and there were instances startActivityForResult() -> onActivityResult() can be called on the Fragment Scope.

The question is, when it is a good practice to call startActivityForResult()->onActivityResult() on Fragment or on Activity()?

This may not solve the problem but this can solve lingering confusion on my mind.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code for us to see why your adapter does not update the data? As for when it is good practice to use these method opinions differentiate, I guess it depends on the problem you have in hand.

Comment: Thanks, if that is the case then this would not be a real problem then. In regards with my current problem, I am able to pin down what causing it. But as I researched more on the problem, I encountered having startActivity and onActivityFromResult from the Fragment Scope and I was confused if there is convention on where should this 2 functions be called/implemented? It seems you can do both on Activity and Fragment. This really confuse me. I wish I could gather use cases that will help me understand.